# Align icons vertically and sideways

Tags: html, css, css-position, flexbox

I am trying to align these previous and next links to be vertically aligned with image in center and pulled sideways (it would need to be responsive, height and width of an image are always different).
Using flex with absolute positioning on previous links seems ok, it aligns to the left although centering is a problem, but the next link in that case goes outside of row, at the bottom right corner..

```
.previous {
    color: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }

<div class="row-attachment-image text-center">
    <a class="previous" href="#">&lt;</a>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
    <a class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

I have set a bootply
http://www.bootply.com/nh0yRF4min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use flexbox, then I'd suggest this:

```
.row-attachment-image {
  background-color: #000;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  }
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/CKjcXtGgoa)